# how to make a radio button condition based in extjs

Tags: extjs

I want to mark one of the radio field based upon some condition and when the condition is not satisfied want to display an error message in window.

```
var item = {
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    columnWidth : 1, 
    columns: 2, 
    id : 'radio', 
    height : 50, 
    itemId:'defaultValue_radio', 
    vertical:false, 
    items: [ 
        {
            boxLabel: 'None',
            name: 'defacultValueType', 
            inputValue: 'None' 
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'All', 
            name: 'defacultValueType', 
            inputValue: 'All' 
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Custom value', 
            name: 'defacultValueType', 
            inputValue: 'Custom value'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Select from list', 
            name: 'defacultValueType', 
            inputValue: 'Select value' 
        } 
    ],
```

Comment: Could you edit your post with a piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `simpleValue` to true inside the `radiogroup`to enable value binding, then you can listen to  `beforerender` event, get the value from your store, or whatever you get it from, set the value and if the value is undefined you return a message.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rqg)

```
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        columnWidth: 1,
        columns: 2,
        id: 'radio',
        height: 50,
        itemId: 'defaultValue_radio',
        vertical: false,
        simpleValue: true,
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'None',
            name: 'defacultValueType',
            inputValue: 'None'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'All',
            name: 'defacultValueType',
            inputValue: 'All'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Custom value',
            name: 'defacultValueType',
            inputValue: 'Custom value'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Select from list',
            name: 'defacultValueType',
            inputValue: 'Select value'
        }],
        listeners: {
            beforerender: function (component, eOpts) {
                let value = 'Custom value'; //get value from store or whatever you like
                component.setValue(value);
                if (!component.getValue()) {
                    Ext.Msg.show({
                        title: 'Error!',
                        message: 'Invalid Value',
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                        icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }]
```

Comment: Doesnt getting the result

Comment: suppose i have 4 radio button , and two values one the button which i clicked now and other the previously clicked button say the newvalue and oldvalue, so on clicking the new button , i want that the old button is clicked. is it possible?

Comment: Sry for not understanding your needs but I don't think this is the expected behaviour of a `radiogroup`, as it only allows one radio button to be 'clicked' why don't you use `checkboxes` instead?

Comment: radiogroup is required..anyways thanks for the help